# How to Tell Regex to Check Whole Sub-String?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

First here is the regex I am working with:

```
       String pattern = @"Create(\s+)Table(\s+)(\([a-z0-9]+\))(\s+)Columns(\s+)((\(([a-z0-9]+);(INTEGER|DECIMAL|STRING);(\d{1,3});(((YES|NO);){3})([a-z0-9]+)\))+)";
        Match CMD = Regex.Match(Command, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (CMD.Success)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

**this regex work as expected for the following patterns:**

1) Create Table (MARKS) Columns  (fountains;StriNg;999;NO;YES;NO;wicked)(rivers;String;500;NO;YES;NO;sweet)

2) Create Table (MARKS) Columns  (ID;Integer;4;YES;YES;YES;0)  (riversString;50;NO;YES;NO;sweet)

in the first pattern the whole string is a match but in the second pattern Only the substring
**Create Table (MARKS) Columns  (ID;Integer;42;YES;YES;YES;0)** is a match

now it returns false false for the following pattern:

3)Create Table (MARKS) Columns  (IDInteger;42;YES;YES;YES;0)  (rivers;String;500;NO;YES;NO;sweet)

the second pattern and the third pattern  have the same error but the only difference is that in the second pattern the match for **\(([a-z0-9]+);(INTEGER|DECIMAL|STRING);(\d{1,3});(((YES|NO);){3})([a-z0-9]+)\)** had already occured before the end of the string and thus regex return true.

Now my question is how can I tell rejects to keep matching until the end of the string?

so basically something like this: isntead of or in addition to the plus Sign (which means One or more matching prevoius) i want => One or more matching until the end of line. this way the third will result in true for substring **Create Table (MARKS) Columns  (rivers;String;500;NO;YES;NO;sweet)** from **Create Table (MARKS) Columns  (IDInteger;42;YES;YES;YES;0)  (rivers;String;500;NO;YES;NO;sweet)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `\s*?` after the closing bracket of the `Columns(...)` group, to match 0+ (lazy) spaces between two `Columns` groups:

```
Create(\s+)Table(\s+)(\([a-z0-9]+\))(\s+)Columns(\s+)((\(([a-z0-9]+);(INTEGER|DECIMAL|STRING);(\d{1,3});(((YES|NO);){3})([a-z0-9]+)\)\s*?)+)
```

The last string doesn't match because you forgot the `;` between ID and Integer.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I understood what you need.

This matches 0+ spaces between `Columns` groups and **keeps searching till it finds a valid group**.

```
Create(\s+)Table(\s+)(\([a-z0-9]+\))(\s+)Columns(\s*\([^)]*\))*(\s*\(([a-z0-9]+);(INTEGER|DECIMAL|STRING);(\d{1,3});(((YES|NO);){3})([a-z0-9]+)\))+
```

See in on RegEx101 http://regex101.com/r/rU6eJ4

**EDIT 2:**

This one only matches string on the same line:

```
Create[^\S\n]+Table[^\S\n]+(\([a-z0-9]+\))[^\S\n]+Columns([^\S\n]*\([^)]*\))*([^\S\n]*\(([a-z0-9]+);(INTEGER|DECIMAL|STRING);(\d{1,3});(((YES|NO);){3})([a-z0-9]+)\))+
```

Comment: Yes I did that on purpose.... But the substring "Create Table (MARKS) Columns (rivers;String;500;NO;YES;NO;sweet)" matches the pattern but because "(IDInteger;42;YES;YES;YES;0)" is infront of "(rivers;String;500;NO;YES;NO;sweet)" it returns false but I want this pattern(pattern 3) to be true

Comment: So you need to specify the `?` modifier on the first `;`

Comment: I see want You saying and I re-factored my code and changed my regex completely... See My answer. Thanks

Comment: @FabioDelarias i've also added an edit that matches only string on the same line (`\s` also matches newline characters).

Answer (score 3):

Use begin (^) and end ($) symbols like:

```
String patter = @"^\d+$";
```

Comment: Yes I know About those symbols but simply putting them at the beginning or at the end still returns false for the third pattern?

Comment: Then it's an issue with main pattern, not line borders

Comment: Yes there is an issue with the main pattern and that's why am asking for help? I tried my best to explain this

Answer (score 0):

Don't just use begin (^) and end ($) symbols, making use of the Global Modifier might fix this particular problem.

String patter = @"/^\d+$/**g**";

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically I decided to break down my regex into two regexes:

```
        String pattern = @"Create(\s+)Table(\s+)(\([a-z0-9]+\))(\s+)Columns(\s+)(((\([a-z0-9;]+\))\s*)+)";
        Match CMD = Regex.Match(Command, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if (CMD.Success)
        {
            String SubCommand = CMD.Groups[6].Value;
            String SubPattern = @"\(([a-z0-9]+);(INTEGER|DECIMAL|STRING);(\d{1,3});(YES|NO);(YES|NO);(YES|NO);([a-z0-9]+)\)";
            MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(SubCommand, SubPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

           if (match.Count != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I think Didn't explain My problem well enough but I thank everyone for their help